# Problem with Code Generated by XSD.EXE: Sequence of Elements is Generated as an Array

Tags: c#, xsd

I am trying to generate C# code from an XSD using xsd.exe

Here is a snippet of the problematic area

```
<xs:element name="EmailConfiguration" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="DefaultSendToAddressCollection" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="EmailAddress" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>

        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

Currently DefaultSendToAddressCollection is being generated as a string[]

How can I change the xsd, so that it is generated as a strong type, and email addresses as a collection to the strong type?

**Question Update:**

Or is xsd.exe bugged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've specified EmailAddress to be of type `xs:string` instead of a complex type - therefore, DefaultSendToAddressCollection is an array of strings, instead of a collection of objects.

If you change EmailAddress to be a complex type, and give it an `xs:attribute` of type `xs:string` to store the address to, you will end up with a collection of EmailAddress objects.

```
<xs:element name="EmailConfiguration" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="DefaultSendToAddressCollection" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="EmailAddress" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="Address" type="xs:string" />
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

Comment: Basically What I want is a collection of emailAddresses or string[]
EmailAddress

What I am getting is string[] DefaultSendToAddressCollection and the generated code has no collection of email addresses.

Comment: Also if you look at the xsd, it seems Email is a complex type:

<xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="EmailAddress" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>

Comment: No, DefaultSendToAddressCollection is the complex type.  The element tag for EmailAddress says type="xs:string" - it's a simple type. I'll whip up an example.

Comment: Remember that if you make a sequence consisting of simple types, it comes out as an array, because really there is no point in having a collection of simple types.  It seems like if all you are storing is just one string, the email address, than having DefaultSendToAddressCollection as a string array should work fine for you.

Comment: What I've specified in my example will make DefaultSendToAddressCollection into a collection of "EmailAddress" objects, which have one string property, "Address".

Comment: Only problem is getting the exception the name attribute is not supported in this context... for the attribute

Comment: JL - the "Name" property on EmailAddress should actually be "name".  Lower case N.  Sorry about that.
I think the attribute should be fine.

Comment: This does change the xml... instead of `<DefaultSendToAddressCollection><EmailAddress>first</EmailAddress><EmailAddress>second</EmailAddress></DefaultSendToAddressCollection>` You now have: `<DefaultSendToAddressCollection><EmailAddress Address="first" /><EmailAddress Address="second" /></DefaultSendToAddressCollection>`... This is not the same!